# WordPress page editor box not showing on blog posts page

Tags: php, wordpress

In the WordPress dashboard admin area....when I go to pages and edit my 'news' page there is no editing box to add content images etc, the page is literally pulling in latest blog posts and that is it, there is no Wysiwig editing box.

Has this been removed via code in the functions file?  Can I reverse it, I want to enable a client to change an image at top of page using the editing box to edit page.

All the other pages have the editing box.

thanks in advance for any help
Vicky

Comment: Do you have permission to edit that page? Have you tried disabling your plugins? How about any errors in the browser's console or on the server? What version of WP are you using?

Comment: Yes have permissions am in as administrator...using latest version of WordPress...will disable plugins and see if that helps. thanks

Comment: No joy....  :/  still not working